# Toggle Switch inside a Tab

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to use a toggle switch inside a tab control, to change the display of data for the current tab.  So I have 3 tabs (Plots, People and Address).  Tabs 2 & 3 are easy as they are just plain text content.  But tab 1 (Plots) I need to filter the display of data.

So I broke this down to try and get two buttons to hide and display the divs as I want them to, but they both just hide everything.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("button").click(function() {
        $("#current").toggle();
      });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("button").click(function() {
        $("#all").toggle();
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <!--<div>
            <input id="current" type="radio" name="group1" value="plots">Current Plots
            <br>
            <input id="all" type="radio" name="group1" value="plots1">All Plots
        </div>-->

  <button class="current">Toggle Current Plots DIV</button>
  <button class="all">Toggle all plots DIV</button>
  <hr>

  <div class="current" id="current">
    <p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
    <p>Paragraph 1 - Current Plots.</p>
    <hr>
  </div>

  <div class="all" id="all">
    <p>This is another small paragraph.</p>
    <p>Paragraph 2 - All Plots</p>
    <hr>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I do not see your code. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What is the goal that you want to achieve? What is the Javascript you have written? How is it failing?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because for your `click` event you are using `button` as a selector, so any `button` element is going to toggle everything. Change the selector to the `class` on the button.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // This changed from button
      $(".current").click(function() {
        $("#current").toggle();
      });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
      // This changed from button
      $(".all").click(function() {
        $("#all").toggle();
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <!--<div>
            <input id="current" type="radio" name="group1" value="plots">Current Plots
            <br>
            <input id="all" type="radio" name="group1" value="plots1">All Plots
        </div>-->

  <button class="current">Toggle Current Plots DIV</button>
  <button class="all">Toggle all plots DIV</button>
  <hr>

  <div class="current" id="current">
    <p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
    <p>Paragraph 1 - Current Plots.</p>
    <hr>
  </div>

  <div class="all" id="all">
    <p>This is another small paragraph.</p>
    <p>Paragraph 2 - All Plots</p>
    <hr>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

### Edit

Adding a more efficient way to handle by creating one function than can handle the buttons using `data` attributes on the button elements.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // Use a data attribute on the button to toggle an element's id.
      $('button').click(function() {
        // get the button's data-target value
        let target = $(this).data('target');
        // use the data-target value to pass as the id of the target element.
        $("#" + target).toggle();
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>


  <button data-target="current">Toggle Current Plots DIV</button>
  <button data-target="all">Toggle all plots DIV</button>
  <hr>

  <div id="current">
    <p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
    <p>Paragraph 1 - Current Plots.</p>
    <hr>
  </div>

  <div id="all">
    <p>This is another small paragraph.</p>
    <p>Paragraph 2 - All Plots</p>
    <hr>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```